# Notepad++ Undo undoes whole replace history

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

In Notepad++ (v6.5), having done a series of Find-and-Replace-All's, hitting CTRL-Z seems to undo the whole series. Hitting CTRL-Y redoes the whole series.

Can you undo only the last Replace-All without quitting and restarting NPP after each replace?

Answer (score 2):

If you used *Replace All*, this is by design. This is obviously counted as a single action. Clicking *Replace* instead will make every action undoable but you'd obviously have to click *Replace* repeatedly.

Perhaps you can use the `In selection` option to selectively find and replace.

Comment: I re-worded the question. I did several Replace-All's in a row, so you should be able to undo one global action after the other.  
It turns out: you can. I restarted NPP and then it worked.

Comment: @RolfBly I can't reproduce your error. Each *Replace All* action is undone properly with my installation of Notepad++. Have you tried to reinstall Notepad++?